# Android no notification on service

Tags: android, service, notifications

when i try to run a notification, nothing pops up

```
private void pushNotification(String user)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Service", "pushNotification");
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("Basic Notification ")
    .setContentText("Basic Notification, used earlier").build();
  notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

1. Is it because i do not have an icon for it?
2. do I need add anything to push the notification?
3. Also, I want to start an activity when I click
   on the notification. What should I do?

Comment: See the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html check this link

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification noty = mBuilder.build();
    startForeground(mId, noty);
```

About activity when you click on the notification look in [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse)

Comment: This will not work as you are not setting notify() method for notificationmanager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification;
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, activity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
                .setContentText(message).build();

        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```